# How to prove the estimator of $\sigma^2$ in generalized least squares is unbiased?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

The model is as follow:

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon, \epsilon \sim (0,\sigma^2 V)$$

where $X$ is $n \times (p+1)$ and $V$ is a known positive definite matrix.

Using spectral decomposition, it can be established that $V$ is positive definite if and only if there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $V = PP^T$. Multiplying $P^{-1}$ on both sides yields that

$$P^{-1}y = P^{-1} X \beta + P^{-1} \epsilon$$

I managed to derive that $\hat{\beta} = (X^T V^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TV^{-1}y$.

The estimator for $\sigma^2$ is as follow
$$\hat{\sigma^2}= \frac{(y-X\hat{\beta})^T V^{-1}(y-X\hat{\beta})}{n-(p+1)}  $$
$$= \frac{y^T(V^{-1}-V^{-1}X(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TV^{-1})y}{n-(p+1)}$$

But I failed to show that the estimator of $\sigma^2$ is **unbiased**

My attempt is to take expectation of $\hat{\sigma^2}$ and then use trace to show that

$$E(\hat{\sigma^2})= \frac{tr(V^{-1}-V^{-1}X(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TV^{-1})) E(yy^T)}{n-(p+1)}$$

Then I got stuck. I do not know how to continue.

Can someone kindly help me here please?

Comment: I used it in the above already and this the part I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your formula when using the trace. The trace of a scalar is of course the scalar itself and because $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ (even for non-square matrices) you have $E(y^{T}Ay) = E(tr(y^{T}Ay)) = E(tr(Ay\,{y^{T}}))$ which, if A is non-random, gives $tr(A.E(y\,{y^{T}}))$. That is to say, the trace is on the product not on A alone.

Correcting your formula we get:

$$E(\hat{\sigma}^2)= \frac{tr((V^{-1}-V^{-1}X{X^{T}V^{-1}X)^{-1}}\,{X^{T}}V^{-1}). E(y\,{y^{T}}))}{n-(p+1)}$$

Now $E(y{y^{T}}) = \sigma^2 V + X\beta\beta^{T}X^{T}$ and if you notice that

$$tr(V^{-1}X{(X^{T}V^{-1}X)^{-1}}\,{X^{T}}) = tr(({X^{T}V^{-1}X){(X^{T}V^{-1}X)^{-1}}}) = tr(I_{p+1}) = p+1$$

And that

$$tr(V^{-1}X{(X^{T}V^{-1}X)^{-1}}\,{X^{T}}V^{-1}X\beta\beta^{T}X^{T}) = tr(V^{-1}X\beta\beta^{T}X^{T}) $$

You get

$$\begin{alignat}{}
tr((V^{-1}-V^{-1}X{(X^{T}V^{-1}X)^{-1}}X^{T}V^{-1}). (\sigma^2 V + X\beta\beta^{T}X^{T})) \\= \sigma^2tr(I_{n}) - \sigma^2tr(I_{p+1})\\ =
\sigma^2(n - (p+1))   
\end{alignat}
$$

Hence, $E(\hat{\sigma}^2) = \sigma^2$ and the estimator is unbiased.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $E(y y^T)$ which yields a covariance matrix instead of $E(y^Ty)$ which yields a scalar variance, since $Cov(y) = E[(y-X\beta)(y-X\beta)^T]$ ? And there should be a plus sign in $E(yy^T) = \sigma^2V + X\beta \beta^T X$

Comment: I've edited the transposition sign to appear on the right. I hope you find the answer clearer now

Comment: there is a ( missing in the first equation - many thanks for this clear explanation!